# Cherry nutrient deficiency from leaf

Tags: nutrients, deficiency

Is it possible to make guesses based on this photo about deficiencies that might be affecting this cherry tree please.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Definitely potassium is deficient - burnt edges
And most likely Zinc - pale new leaves

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).